# Spring MVC Rest - How can I know if a user loses their connection while waiting on response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring 4 MVC application that is serving a rest API. I am trying to debug an issue where it appears that users are losing their connection, but I'm not sure how to capture this information at the application level.

Is there a logging level or something I can turn on? In the logs, it looks like the request just stops processing, but I don't see any error.

Answer (score 0):

What you can not check is the download-speed because its hardware-buffer is block-based. You may be able to set the block-size to 1byte, so the time-effort is multipicated in small bandwidths. This might give a exception if the socket is closed.

To provoce some exceptions you could decrease the socket timeout (the time waiting for a byte to be read). This is a configuration issue, you should check the web-container's documentation (`connectionTimeout` in tomcat).

Not every OS is supporting this SO_TIMEOUT, but the common OS's should be able to configure it.

Anyway, it is a task for the web-container (like tomcat) and therefore its detached from the application (for a good reason from my point of view).

You may check the chrome-browser devtools let you emulate slow bandwidths.